# Remove List Items for SP List Exceeded Threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, pnp-powershell

I have a SPO list where the threshold has exceeded the threshold of 5000. I need to remove 6761785 items and counting.

I have tried to use the following PNP but not having much joy

```
$items=Get-PnPListItem -List e517d0da-3c1c-47cd-946d-9d295c52f1cd -PageSize 1000
foreach ($item in $items)
{
Write-Host "Getting Items for ListItemID=$($item.Id)" -ForegroundColor Green
try
    {
    Remove-PnPListItem -List “e517d0da-3c1c-47cd-946d-9d295c52f1cd” -Identity $item.Id -Force
    Write-Host "Removing ListItemID=$($item.Id)" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
catch
            {
            Write-Host “error”
            }

}
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

- Any advise welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, the PnP PowerShell in your post can work fine.

And you also could export the list to the excel file and delete the original list. Then import the excel file to the new list.

And you could choose the data in excel file to import to the new list.

To export to excel in list in SharePoint online, you could refer to the article below.

Export to Excel from SharePoint.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-to-Excel-from-SharePoint-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9

To import excel file to SharePoint list, you could refer to the article below.

Create a list based on a spreadsheet.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa

Comment: Thank you Amy.  How would I export to excel and clear and re-import?

Comment: I have updated my reply.